# Proof about the size of a particular given set.

Tags: combinatorics

Okay so I'm working on this question:

[image]

I have done the first bit and parts i) and ii) getting answers $20 \choose 10$, $10!$ and $10 \choose 2$ as my answers respectively. I'm stuck on the part iii) though even with the hint. I can show the existence of a particular case but not sure that there must be these subsets. I was thinking if I could find all the possible sums and then show that there are more sets than possible sums and then apply the pigeonhole principle to do my answer but I couldn't work out how many different sums there were or how many sets there were.

Any ideas?

Comment: An approach to a solution for part (iii) is as follows: What are the minimum and maximum possible sums for two numbers from $S$?  And how many different possible combinations of two numbers are there in $S$?  (See part (ii).)  Finally, if two sets of size two $A$ and $B$, not identical and both subsets of $S$, have the same sum, are they necessarily disjoint?

Comment: Maximum sum would be $39$ and minimum would be $3$.  So there are $36$ total sums. There are $10 \choose 2 $ possible combinations, i.e. $45$, so using the pigeonhole principle we must have two sets that satisfy this?

Comment: There are 37 possible sums between 3 and 39, inclusive.  But otherwise, yes, your reasoning is correct.  To make it watertight, you must establish that two sets of size two that have the same sum must be either disjoint or identical.  This is fairly trivial, but it must be included in your reasoning.

Comment: Okay thanks how exactly would I go about showing that the 2 sets are disjoint? It doesn't seem trivial to me?

Comment: Suppose you have two sets $A$ and $B$, both of size two and having the same sum.  There are three possible cases: (a) They are disjoint.  This satisfies the condition.  (b) They are identical.  This satisfies the condition.  (c) They have exactly one number in common.  Is this possible?  (Hint: What would the other numbers be in $A$ and $B$?)

Comment: How would b) satisfy the condition? (they wouldn't be distinct then???) c) isn't possible though since if they had one number in then the other number must be the same if the sums are the same.

Comment: Got it thanks!!!!!!!!!!